# How to find which all are the built in data types for UML class diagram in Lucidchart?

Tags: uml, lucidchart

In Lucidchart, which all data types are built in to use for attributes and parameters in class diagram?

Comment: This isn't really a programming question.

Comment: [Welcome to StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please read our [ask] page for hints on how to improve your
 question. Great questions tend to generate quicker, better answers from the community.

Comment: I do not know Lucidchart, but the default "PrimitiveType" elements are Integer, Boolean, String, UnlimitedNatural, and Real. (see chapter 21.1. of UML 2.5 specifications)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A UML Class Diagram is simply a way to structure data about the way your code is organized. What you put into the diagram is entirely up to you and is dictated by the part of the code you are diagramming. You can try searching online for introductory guides for class diagrams that will give examples.

Within Lucidchart, absolutely any text content is valid within a UML Class Diagram shape. You will notice that the class diagram shapes contain some default text when you first add them to your diagram. This text is just an example of one notation you could use to annotate your classes and objects that you represent in your diagram. Lucidchart is just a tool that is designed to be as nonrestrictive as possible as you create your class diagram. It does not perform any logic to verify the attributes or parameters you choose to list in your diagram.